# Is there a transitive set of finite sets with cardinality > $2^{ℵ_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to find if there is a transitive set of finite sets with cardinality > $2^{ℵ_0}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : If a set is transitive and contains only finite sets, then it can only contain hereditarily finite sets. How many hereditarily finite sets are there ?